# Adaptive UI with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm developing a new ios 8 application using SpriteKit. Recently I read a lot about adaptive UI but found no way to implement it with SpriteKit.
Suppose for example that I programmatically create a subclass of SKNode, call it MyNode.
In interface builder there is nothing that lets me put on the screen the node I just created.
I found on raywenderlich a snippet of code that checkes whether the app is running in iPad or iPhone and resizes a playable area of 320x480 opportunely.
Is there a method to adapt the ui with ib? Or should I do this programmatically via that snippet? Thanks.

This is an example of what I mean. These are the app screens in iPad and iPhone. How do you think the developer achieved the goal?

[iPad](http://wp6109-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/letterpress_2012_awards.png)
[iPhone](http://wordgamestrategies.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/IMG_40921.png)